# How can I incorporate LaTeX into an iBook created with iBooks Author?

Tags: latex, ibooks-author

I'm interested in writing a text in the sciences that requires some mathematical notation, but I see no way to incorporate LaTeX into iBooks using iBooks Author.

Am I missing a feature? Is there an add-on plug-in architecture (e.g. using "widgets") that would allow me to add a tool for LaTeX editing. Are there any existing LaTeX "widgets" or add-ons?

---

Ideally, I'm seeking something other than a "one-way" static PDF- or image-generation approach.

Comment: Of course you want more than a "one-way" generated rendering. So do I; you just beat me to posting this question! I posted a one-way solution as an answer in the hope that it might help generate a more useful answer, and one-way is better than no way.

Comment: Let Apple know about this issue :
http://www.apple.com/feedback/ibooks-author.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## [LaTeXiT](http://www.chachatelier.fr/latexit/)

...is the solution I'll go with now. You can export your Latex as a picture which can be very easily copied into iBooks Author.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

IF you rendered the LaTeX into a PDF, you could certainly paste the resulting image into iBooks Author, but this is hardly an optimal solution.